# Retrieve data, strange behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF 6 to retrieve some data from SQL Server. I encountered this problem in the past, but I haven't asked anyone about it.

For the below code, just focus on the select.

Let's say in the database I have 2 rows:

```
1 2 3 4  5 
6 7 8 9 10
```

My code:

```
 var results = db.Table.Where(o => o.Version == 1)
                       .Select(o => new List<double?>{ o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05});

 return results.ToList();
```

The code above will return a list of lists with the following:

```
previousDemand[0] = 1 2 3 4 5
previousDemand[1] = 10 9 8 7 6
```

The second list is reversed.

If I have more rows, it happens the same: first ok, second reversed, third ok, fourth reversed and so on.

If I change the code to this:

```
 var results = db.Table.Where(o => o.Version == 1).ToList();
 var x = results.Select(o => new List<double?>{ o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05});

 return x.ToList();
```

everything will work fine here.

If seems there is a problem if I create lists within the EF query.

Am I missing something important?

**UPDATE**
**Adding some screenshots:**
[image: Sql Server]

[image: What i receive in EF]

Comment: And how generated sql queries looks like in both cases?

Comment: Since you're not **explicitly** asking for any particular order, and you're going against SQL Server, the ordering in which the values are returned is **not defined** - SQL Server is free to return them in any order it might chose to do. If you **need ordering** - then you must **explicitly define it** - with an `.OrderBy` in EF, or an `ORDER BY` In T-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reproducible glitch in the way EF materializes a `List<T>` object from values originating from one database record. It turns out that the executed SQL statement returns the values in this unexpected alternating order. That means that EF generates a SQL query that is never guaranteed to return a specific order. But since SQL is a set-based language it never gives any guarantee as to the order of elements in a set. It would be possible to generate a query SQL that orders the elements correctly, but I think EF never anticipated your (not so common) scenario, or didn't think it worth the effort to support it.

Since it's part of EF's source code, there's no quick way to fix it and you'll have to settle with your work-around. You may want to file a bug report.

The root problem IMO is bad data normalization. If your table would be the parent of a table of `M` records --each representing one double value, maybe with a sequence field-- it would be much easier to obtain this list of lists.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

<s>`new List<double?> { o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05 }.OrderBy(p => p).ToList()`</s>

That sugestion does only work on the sample you provided, but does not solve your problem, as pointed by @GertArnold on the comments.

What you could do instead is not query for a list, but instead return a new entity, with the columns you want. After materializing the result, you could turn it to a list.

```
var results = 
   db.Entities.Where(o => o.Version == 1)
     .Select(o => new { M01 = o.M01, M02 = o.M02, M03 = o.M03, M04 = o.M04, M05 = o.M05 });

return results.Select(o => new List<double?> { o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05 });
```

**Now the reasoning:**

Your EF query generates the following (really messy) SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project6].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project6].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN ([UnionAll4].[C1] = 0) THEN [Extent1].[M01] 
                WHEN ([UnionAll4].[C1] = 1) THEN [Extent1].[M02] 
                WHEN ([UnionAll4].[C1] = 2) THEN [Extent1].[M03] 
                WHEN ([UnionAll4].[C1] = 3) THEN [Extent1].[M04] 
                ELSE [Extent1].[M05] END AS [C1], 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            1 AS [C2]
        FROM  [dbo].[Entities] AS [Extent1]
        CROSS JOIN  (
            SELECT 0 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]                
            UNION ALL               
                SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]                
            UNION ALL               
                SELECT 2 AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]             
            UNION ALL               
                SELECT 3 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]                
            UNION ALL               
                SELECT 4 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]
            ) AS [UnionAll4]
            WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Version]
    )  AS [Project6]
ORDER BY [Project6].[Id] ASC, [Project6].[C2] ASC
```

As you can see on the ORDER BY clause, the query orders by [Project6].[C2], which is just a control flag that returns 1.
This is because, as @marc_s specified in the comments, you didn't explicitly specify an order for your results.

If you would instead use somenting like:

<s>var results = 
       db.Entities.Where(o => o.Version == 1)
         .Select(o => new List { o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05 }.OrderBy(p => p).ToList());</s>

... then the generated SQL would include the correct order clause and you would get the exepcted result.

```
var results = 
   db.Entities.Where(o => o.Version == 1)
     .Select(o => new { M01 = o.M01, M02 = o.M02, M03 = o.M03, M04 = o.M04, M05 = o.M05 });

return results.Select(o => new List<double?> { o.M01, o.M02, o.M03, o.M04, o.M05 });
```

... then you wouldn't need to bother with the generated SQL order and would have control over the order your columns are returned on the output list.

Comment: But M01, M02, M03, M04, M05 are columns of a table. How is EF mapping first row like: M01 = 1, M02 = 2, M03 = 3, M04 = 4, M05 = 5 and the second row like: M01 = 10, M02 = 9, M03 = 8, M04 = 7, M05 = 6? Order by is ordering the results. My question is about mapping wrongly the columns of one row, not about how the results are ordered. Maybe I was unclear. I will post some screenshots to be more specific later.

Comment: @BogdanC.You are mapping your results to a list. There's nothing wrong with EF's mapping, but with what you are doing with it, If you were to map your result to, say, a new class with the five props you need, you wouldn't have the problem of SQL returning an arbitrarely ordered result set that's added to a list. Try doing something like `Select(o => new { M01 = o.M01, M02 = o.M02, M03 = o.M03, M04 = o.M04, M05 = o.M05 });` to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @BogdanC. Btw, have you tried the solution I suggested? I'm sure it will fix your problem...

Comment: This merely orders the lists by their values, it doesn't reconstruct the order of the `Mxx` fields. The SQL statement, without `OrderBy`, returns the values in correct order. It's EF that messes them up.

Comment: @GertArnold good point. You are right about my solution being wrong.The query **does not** return the results in the right order, though. Repro his scenario on EF and execute the internal query agains the DB to check it out.

Comment: @Gabriel Rainha your edited solution also works fine. I also had a workaround for the "problem". I just wanted to know what am I doing wrong with the first syntax. By what Gert Arnold said, it's an EF glitch.

Comment: @GabrielRainha You're absolutely right. I did test the SQL statement when I wrote the answer, but somehow didn't notice the alternating order. I changed my answer accordingly.